# How to find all oldest sibling in all families

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I have a lot of families represented like:

```
(parent:Person)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(child:Person {age:19})
```

then how would a query look like that finds the oldest child of all families?

I have the following suggestion, but this only returns 1 node:

```
match (parent:Person)<--(child:Person) return child order by child.age desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably can be optimized, here's a quick go at it-

```
match (c:Person)-[:CHILD_OF]->(p)
with p, max(c.age) as maxAge, collect(c) as children
return p,filter (x in children where x.age=maxAge)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
match (parent:Person)<--(child:Person) with parent, max(child.age) as maxAge
Match (parent)<--(child:Person) where child.age = maxAge
return *
```

It might return several childs if they have maximum same age, if you want to return one, you should use one more creteria like 
max(id(child))
and you will have

```
Match (parent:Person)<--(child:Person) with parent, max(child.age) as maxAge
Match (parent)<--(child:Person) where child.age = maxAge with parent, max(id(child)) as maxId
Match (parent)<--(child:Person) where id(child) = maxId return *
```